# Overlap list item with another child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I have list of items. When hover, the background should highlight gray per item. I also want to be able to hover on "X" to change its background to red.

However, in the code below, when I hover on each line, the item background lays on top of "X" and there is no way to hover on "X".

**Code:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/7vtZT/2/

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Long title for Item 1</a>
        <i class=icon></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 2</a>
        <i class=icon></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 3</a>
        <i class=icon></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 4</a>
        <i class=icon></i>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Item 5</a>
        <i class=icon></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    border: 1px solid green;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100px;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px;
}

a:hover {
    background: gray;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -20px;
    background: yellow;
}

.icon:before {
    content: "X";
}

.icon:hover:before {
    background: red;
}
```

**Question:** How to change CSS (preferably) to be able to hover on "X" to change its background color & be "clickable" in JS but also have the item's background in that line highlighted gray?

Right now I cannot event hook "click" event in the "X" because it keeps going under the items.

**Requirements**:

1. Width for `ul` is fixed of `100px`
2. "X" must be in the same line of each `li a` element and stays in `ul`'s width
3. If text in `a` is too long, it must go under "X" but not show outside box `ul`. There is no wrap.
4. Each `li a` has hardcoded width with `ellipsis` to show "..." on long text. This width can be changed.
5. No Javascript. Hardcoded CSS position is OK but less prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the anchor css from `inline-block` to `block` also as a recommendation change the width from 100px (which is hardcoded) to 100% our auto to set the same width as the container

[fiddle solution](http://jsfiddle.net/7vtZT/5/)

Comment: fixed, with z-index, check the new link

Comment: I saw you added `position:relative;` to `.icon` too. How does that impact the element in term of its `z-index`? Just curious.

Comment: in order to set a stack of elements they have to be in a position relative or absolute without it there's no way to handle the z-index stack

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: relative;` to all the `li` and add `position: absolute;`, `right: 0;`, `top: 0;` to `.icon`

[Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7vtZT/4/)

Answer (score 0):

May this can help u i think so..

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 80px;
    height:15px;
}
```